# Install wxPython 3.0.0.0 from source in virtualenv under Ubuntu linux

Tags: python, wxpython, virtualenv, wxwidgets

I want to install wxPython 3.0.0.0 in virtualenv under Ubuntu 14.04.
You can't do it using `pip install`.
I've read a lot of notes about installing wxPython from source, but they didn't help me.
I've done the following steps:

```
$ mkdir myenv
$ cd myenv
$ source bin/activate
(myenv)$ wget http://downloads.sourceforge.net/wxpython/wxPython-src-3.0.0.0.tar.bz2
(myenv)$ tar xjvf wxPython-src-3.0.0.0.tar.bz2
```

What should I do further?  How should I execute (what options?) the
`./configure`, `make` and `make install` commands in wxPython-src-3.0.0.0 directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Run `./configure` - it will check whether you have all required tools and libs.
   Read all error messages and install missing elements.
   If you have all required elements then `./configure` will create `makefile`.
2. Run `make` - it wiil use `makefile` to compile `wxPython`.
3. Run `make install` - it will use `makefile` to copy `wxPython` to the required directories.

That's all.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't account for installing in a virtualenv specifically.